# Xcode Swift Moving UIElements based on screen size

Tags: swift, xcode, screen-size, xcode8

I am creating a simple app and I have three views at the bottom of the screen in two rows.  On landscape / wider screens I would like to drop the top row down to the bottom row.

```
|       Portrait       |   |              Landscape                |
| AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA |   |         AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA          |
| BBBBBBB      CCCCCCC |   | BBBBBBB                       CCCCCCC |
------------------------   -----------------------------------------
```

Is there a couple lines of Swift code that will let me do the following?

```
If (left edge of A) > (right edge of B) then set the (bottom of A to the Bottom of B)
```

Notes
1) A is always Centered
2) B and C are the same size
3) B is attached to the left edge
4) C is attached to the right edge

Comment: You should take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Comment: I have read through that doc and I am not seeing how I can configure a stack so that it hasten row when it can otherwise it has two rows.  Can you provide some more specifics?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the moving of the frame/component when the screen is wide enough

```
@IBOutlet weak var aaaVertPosition: NSLayoutConstraint!

// in viewDidAppear
moveAaaStack

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    moveAaaStack()
}

func moveAaaStack() {
    let aaaFrame: CGRect = selectedAaaOutlet.frame
    let bbbFrame: CGRect = selectedBbbOutlet.frame
    let leftEdgeOfAAA = aaaFrame.origin.x
    let rightEdgeOfBBB = bosFrame.origin.x + bosFrame.size.width
    print("AAA = \(leftEdgeOfAAA) & BBB = \(rightEdgeOfBBB)")
    if (leftEdgeOfAAA + 8 > rightEdgeOfBBB) {
        print("*** Moving AAA Stack down ***")
        aaaVertPosition.constant = 8
    } else {
        print("*** Moving AAA Stack up ***")
        aaaVertPosition.constant = 68.5
    }
}
```